# Logging samba share network activity

Tags: linux, networking, logging, samba, server-message-block

For the purpose of this question, I have a server called `server1` hosting the samba network share `share1` on my local network. `User1` can access this share with read and write permissions.

I'm looking to be able to log every bit of activity in a simple, plain basic format that occurs in the share.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
[DATESTAMP][TIMESTAMP] User1 accessed share1 from device1
[DATESTAMP][TIMESTAMP] User1 opened folder1
[DATESTAMP][TIMESTAMP] User1 deleted file 'filename'
[DATESTAMP][TIMESTAMP] User1 created folder 'folder2'
[DATESTAMP][TIMESTAMP] User1 created file 'file1'
```

And so on.

In a really simple to read format that logs all types of activity such as the creation and deletion of files and folders, accessing files and folders, renaming, deleting, moving, permission changes, etc (maybe even execution of a file)

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in other words you want to set up auditing?

Great, that's supported with: [`vfs objects = full_audit`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_full_audit.8.html) in your `smb.conf` configuration file. The events will be logged to syslog (Adjust the syslog settings in both smb.conf and syslog to get the right events logged in a specific file.)

Adjust what exact events you want to log with the full_audit:success and failure settings.

You can somewhat adjust the formatting by adjusting the prefix. The prefix from the example [`%u|%I`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) uses variable substitutions and will record the username and client IP-address separated by a <kbd>|</kbd>.

```
[records]
    path = /data/records
    vfs objects = full_audit
    full_audit:prefix = %u|%I
    full_audit:success = open opendir
    full_audit:failure = all !open
    full_audit:facility = LOCAL7
    full_audit:priority = ALERT
```

Comment: Is there any way to edit the format even more? To have it put really simply in a log file, do you also know where I can find all the "%" and their meanings (e.g. %u) - and where I can find all of the actions eg. opendir - is there a site or man page to help? Many thanks

Comment: @OJRICKETTS I had already linked to both the manual of the auditing module as well as the smb.conf manual where the different % expansions are documented.

Comment: Thank you very much